# CSS Styling with Different Google Translate Languages?

Tags: html, css, google-translate

The free widget version of google translate (which now allows for individual website word customization) is a very valuable tool.  The site I'm working on is responsive to fit on multiple mobile and desktop devices.  I've got a very discriminating customer who insists on perfect centering for all elements always no matter which device or orientation used.  My problem is our main menu has wildly different widths depending on which language you are looking at (the website, written in English, also supports Chinese, Japanese, and Spanish)

I'd like to be able to control padding, margins and spacing differently depending on which language is in use.

Is there a way to change padding/margin/location of a `<div>` based on CSS selectors and the google translate language in use?

Hmm.. I guess JS/ JQuery to determine widths and respond accordingly is always available, but I'm thinking CSS might be an better way to go. This site already has a lot of javascript/jQuery... I worry about potential conflicts / overhead, etc....  I'd prefer to do this via CSS.  Any ideas?

Note: the site does show me this in html, but nothing that I can see in html class or id's is language specific. The html code always displays lang="en-US" no matter which language is used.

```
<html id="html_element" class="js translated-ltr" lang="en-US" style="min-height: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

When I'm not in translate mode, that code is:

```
<html id="html_element" class="js" lang="en-US" style="min-height: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

Comment: does the lang="en-US" change based on the translated language? I would set up a simple on change jQuery code to apply a CSS style to the "js translated-ltr" class based on the value of the lang parameter. It's low overhead since it only processes when you change the language.

Comment: No, lang= does not change.  See update.  When in translate mode, I get an added class = "translated-ltr" but lang= always holds at "en-US"  I was hoping the -ltr class suffix would change but no go.  No where do I see chinese, japanese or spanish listed in any elements.

Comment: `lang` always changes based on the language you are using.

Comment: Nope. The widget version of google translate does a javascript translate and pushes the content to the element contents. I don't see anywhere where a class or id or font or lang changes..

Comment: what happens when you do an arabic translation? which obviously has different character types than english. It can't possibly go unchanged

Comment: If `lang` doesn't change, it would appear that would be a bug with Google Translate.  I'd report that to them, assuming you have no conflicting scripts preventing the `lang` attribute from changing.

Comment: This site is based on a purchased wordpress template.  We are not using any language translate plug ins.  Its probably best to create an entirely new wordpress site, perhaps using the default wordpress template and retest a few things... @Axel, Adjit, do you know for a fact that the Google Translate widget will reset lang= ??